# Display auto-increment amount in JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wish to animate auto increment on the amount of jackpot as i want the increment start from 4 until the end. As i have working javascript but this javascript contains onclick and i wish not to onclick

how do we do it ?

MY html :

```
<div class="ticker">
    <div id="total-ticker" class="total-ticker"><span class="jackpot jackpot_num">2</span> <span class="jackpot jackpot-comm">&nbsp;</span><span class="jackpot jackpot_num">5</span> <span class="jackpot jackpot_num">6</span> <span class="jackpot jackpot_num">2</span> <span class="jackpot jackpot-comm">&nbsp;</span><span class="jackpot jackpot_num">3</span> <span class="jackpot jackpot_num">0</span> <span class="jackpot jackpot_num">7</span> <span class="jackpot jackpot-dot">&nbsp;</span><span class="jackpot jackpot_num">9</span> <span class="jackpot jackpot_num">4</span> </div>
</div>
```

Example :

```
$2  5 6 2  3 0 7  9 4
```

Javascript :

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
  animateCount : function (from, to, time) {
    var steps = 1,
        self = this,
        counter;

    if (from - to > 0) {
      steps = -1;
    };

    from -= steps;

    function step() {
      self.val(from += steps);

      if ((steps < 0 && to >= from) || (steps > 0 && from >= to)) {
        clearInterval(counter);
      };
    };

    counter = setInterval(step, time || 100);
  }
});

$('#runner').click(function() {
    $('#count').animateCount(1,100);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple...take the counter plugin initialization out of the click handler and initialize when page loads instead

```
$(function(){// make sure dom is ready  
    $('#count').animateCount(1,100);
});
```